# How to add media play/pause button into push notification bar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios9, ios10

I successfully created an apple push notification. I am receiving audio URL via push notification. I want to add media play/pause button into notification bar (custom notification bar), which functionality is that upon getting audio notification the user is able to play/pause receiving audio without opening an app.

Is it possible in iOS? I've searched through many web documents, but found nothing. So, can anyone help me out with this concept?